# How to get selected dropdownvalue in AjaxFileUpload onuploadComplete event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
      <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs"  Inherits="test"%>

      <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server">
       <title></title>
      </head>
      <body style="height: 162px">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:RadioButton ID="MCA" runat="server" Text="MCA" AutoPostBack="True" 
        oncheckedchanged="MCA_CheckedChanged" />
    <br />

</div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Sem1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Sem2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <asp:ListItem Value="MCA101"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MCA103">MCA103</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <br />
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnUploadComplete="upload"/>
    <br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Event Code..

```
      protected void upload(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
      {
        string s = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string t = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        string path= string path = Server.MapPath("~/MCA/" + s + "/" +t+ "/")+e.FileName 
      }
```

//Both s and t get the first value of Dropdownlist even if some other value selected and that's uploading is not done as per directort structure.

Both Dropdownlist have several values and **postback** property is true for both the list.

How to get the exact selected value of list ?

Comment: Post your .aspx page code

Comment: @KPL i posted .aspx code

Answer (score 0):

Issue is `Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] = null` when AjaxFileUpload OnUploadComplete event is called.

**Fix for this issue** (C# Code):

Set dropdown selection in session at page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] != null)
    Session["Path"] = "//" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "//" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "//";
}
```

Use session value for the creation of filepath:

```
protected void upload(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        string path = string.Empty;
        if (Session["Path"] != null)
            path = Server.MapPath("~//MCA" + (string)Session["Path"]) + e.FileName;
}
```

Comment: No change !! still the file is uploading into the MCA\sem1\MCA101 ..

even if MCA103 is selected..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to add the drop down lists to the same update panel as the upload control.